# how to do more with ionic push (ionic.cloud/$ionicPush)

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, android-notifications

I am building an ionic app using sublime because I find it to be more simpler than android studio.

currently I am addion push notification using ionic.cloud with fcm to send push notifications

I foolowed the instructions here: https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/

currently the notifications are working but I want to add more functionality namely

- do specific action when notification is received in background/foreground
- access payload

the snippet below is shows some code from the link above. are there additional functions for the ionicPush object or is there another way to achieve the functionality stated above?

```js
ionicPush.register().then(function(t) {
  return $ionicPush.saveToken(t);
}).then(function(t) {
  console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
});
```